# Is the kanji in this scene a mistake or some kind of joke?

Tags: kanji

My friend was watching the anime みつどもえ 増量中！, and in the first episode there is a scene where basically there is a protest happening against the kind of "power rangers" in this show.

[image]

It's the one on the left sign. Glancing at it I thought it was some weird version of 対 but when I actually looked at it realized that wasn't it. Someone else said that it could be a joke about father and opposition (父 and 対) since it's all parents revolting. I considered that but I think that's really kinda stretching it.

Any help and insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I highly doubt that it is a mistake, but without being familiar with this manga, its author or his/her sense of humor, I could not answer your question.  To answer, one would need to know what kinds of jokes are often made in the series.

Comment: That's kind of how I feel as well. It's not a series I watch or read myself so I'm not sure if these kind of jokes have been used before. Sorry I can't help with that. Thank you for your comment anyways.

Comment: In a Japanese picket sign, some people use slightly different font style called ゲバ文字. However, this is not correct ゲバ文字. Well, I am not sure.
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B2%E3%83%90%E5%AD%97

Answer (score 4):

It is a mistake. You can clearly see this is a demonstration and the sign has "反対" written which is the stereotypical word thrown at demonstrations.

The traditional form of the character is 對 so it is clearly an error, as this is using 交 as a radical for 対 (it has nothing to do with 父 in this context)